# Is there a need to use synchronized when using Concurrent APIs

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

Is there a need to use `synchronized` when working with Concurrent APIs? In other words is there a difference between this

```java
class MessageQueue {

    Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<>();


    public void post(String msg) {
        synchronized (q) {
            q.add(msg);
        }
    }

    public String get() {

        synchronized (q) {
            return q.poll();
        }
    }

}
```

this,

```java
class MessageQueue2 {

    Queue<String> q = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    public void post(String msg) {
            q.add(msg);
    }

    public String get() {
            return q.poll();
    }

}
```

and this ?

```java
class MessageQueue3 {

    Queue<String> q = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();




    public void post(String msg) {
        synchronized (q) {
            q.add(msg);
        }
    }

    public String get() {

        synchronized (q) {
            return q.poll();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Reading and writing the queue doesn't have to be synchronized. You only have to synchronize, if you want to replace the Queue object with a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrent containers are safe to use from multiple threads. That means operations that modify the container take care of synchronization, i.e. multiple threads modifying the container will not corrupt it. So for this particular usage, #1 and #2 are functionally equivalent, and #3 uses redundant synchronization.

That doesn't mean you can implement any algorithm using a concurrent container and remove synchronization.

If the algorithm involves multiple shared objects or more than one operation on the same object, then you need a synchronized block to enclose all operations even if you use a concurrent container. Without an enclosing synchronized block, other threads may run concurrently and create a race condition, even if the containers are thread-safe.

Comment: Agreed. I understand  the broader necessity of synchronization (say a simple notify). The question was about the need for using `synchronized` on ConcurrencyAPIs which I think you are saying is redundant.

Comment: For this particular case, yes it is redundant.